# Java - For loop (do/while) repeats indefinitely

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, while-loop, for-else

I have been working on a project for my course. It's a simple salary calculator, which I have figured out fairly easily and it functions flawlessly. It also takes into consideration benchmarks for commission. I have completed choped on the last part, however. I cannot get it to function. It either loops indefinitely, or it generates static numbers under the "Total Compensation" column (they should be dynamic based on commission etc).

- Bob makes $85,000 a year.
- He gets no bonus/commission if he sells less than $120,000
- He gets 15% commission if his sales for the year are >= $120,000
- He gets an additional 2% for every $150k in sales (150k, 300k, 450k
  etc)

User inputs a sales number (example: $300,000).
Program calculates BaseSalary + ($300,000 * .15) + ($300,000 * .02)

Potential Sales on the left and then Total Compensation on the right side

```
200,000 ----------------------> (Calculated)

220,000 ----------------------> (Calculated)

240,000 ----------------------> (Calculated)

260,000 ----------------------> (Calculated)

280,000 ----------------------> (Calculated)

300,000 ----------------------> (Calculated)
```

---

```
//Variables defined here
        double Sales = input.nextDouble();
        double TotalCompensation;
        int Commission;
        double CommissionRate;
        double AcceleratedCommissionRate;
        int BaseSalary;
        double TargetSales;
        double Accelerator;
        double AcceleratorGoal;
        double AcceleratedCommission;

// Mathematical Operations
        Accelerator = 0.80;
        TargetSales = 150000;
        CommissionRate = 0.15;
        AcceleratedCommissionRate = ((CommissionRate) * (2.0));
        BaseSalary = 85000;
        Commission = (int) (Sales * CommissionRate);
        AcceleratedCommission = (double) (Sales * AcceleratedCommissionRate);
        AcceleratorGoal = (double) 120000; 


// If Else Logic Flow

        if(Sales < AcceleratorGoal)
        {
            TotalCompensation = BaseSalary;
            System.out.print("\nCommission Goal HAS NOT been met");
            System.out.println("\nTotal annual compensaton is: ");
            System.out.println(numberFormat.format(TotalCompensation));

        }

        else if(Sales < TargetSales)
        {
            TotalCompensation = BaseSalary + Commission;
            System.out.print("\nCommission Goal HAS been met");
            System.out.println("\nTotal annual compensaton is: ");
            System.out.println(numberFormat.format(TotalCompensation));
        }

        else if(Sales >= TargetSales)
        {
            TotalCompensation = BaseSalary + AcceleratedCommission;
            System.out.print("\nAccelerator Goal HAS been met");
            System.out.println("\nTotal annual compensaton is: ");
            System.out.println(numberFormat.format(TotalCompensation));

        }

// Potential Commission Structure Table

        double PotentialSales;
        double EndLoop = (Sales * 1.5);
        int Increment = 20000;

            System.out.println("\nPotential Sales\t\tTotal Compensation");

            for (PotentialSales = Sales; PotentialSales < EndLoop; 
            PotentialSales = PotentialSales += Increment)   
            {

                do
                {
                    String output = numberFormat.format(PotentialSales) + "\t\t" 
                    + numberFormat.format(BaseSalary);

                    System.out.println(output);
                }   
                    while(PotentialSales < AcceleratorGoal);

                do
                {
                    String output = numberFormat.format(PotentialSales) + "\t\t" 
                    + numberFormat.format(Commission + BaseSalary);

                    System.out.println(output);
                }
                    while(PotentialSales >= AcceleratorGoal && PotentialSales < TargetSales);

                do
                {
                    String output = numberFormat.format(PotentialSales) + "\t\t" 
                    + numberFormat.format(AcceleratedCommission + BaseSalary);

                    System.out.println(output);
                }
                    while(PotentialSales >= TargetSales);

            }
```

Any suggestions or tips whatsoever would be a lifesaver.

Comment: Infinite loops because your while loop condition is always true.. Did you try debug your code or print the values of "PotentialSales ,TargetSales, AcceleratorGoal " and see what cause the issue this?

Comment: The increment condition in for loop PotentialSales = PotentialSales += Increment. what exactly this means ?

Answer (score 2):

This code will iterate until expression `(PotentialSales < AcceleratorGoal)` is `false`. As you are not updating the value of `PotentialSales` & `AcceleratorGoal` in the body of `do{..body..}while(expression)`, it will iterate indefinitely if `(PotentialSales < AcceleratorGoal)` is `true` at first place, otherwise it will get executed once and will go to the next statement after the `while` condition.

**Code**

```
do{
    String output = numberFormat.format(PotentialSales) + "\t\t" + numberFormat.format(BaseSalary);                   
    System.out.println(output);
}while(PotentialSales < AcceleratorGoal);
```

You might want to update the `PotentialSales` or `AcceleratorGoal` Value inside the body of do while loop or change condition w.r.t `output` variable.

Same goes for next two `do..while` loops.

Comment: Don't use code formatting for text that isn't code. There was no need for all the other bizarre formatting either. It just makes the post illegible.

Comment: And it won't 'iterate indefinitely if `(PotentialSales < AcceleratorGoal)` is true at first place'. It will execute once, and again if that condition is then true, and so on.

Comment: I didn't get sir EJP, that what I meant also, the first place of if `(PotentialSales < AcceleratorGoal)` condition is after execution of loop once i.e the while condition.. and since the value of both PotentialSales and AcceleratorGoal is not changing inside the loop . It will iterate indefinitely.  My answer was on the assumption that the OP knows the execution flow of do..while loop.

Comment: Hey guys, I genuinely appreciate the help. This has solved my problem! It didn't dawn on my that I was not even updating PotentialSales and it was repeating indefinitely. Thanks very much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Your do while loop repeats infinitely because,you are not updating the value of PotentialSales in do while loop

To understand the problem,check the following code

```
int accelerationsales=5;
for(int potentialsales=0;potentialsales<5;potentialsales=potentialsales+=1) {
do {
    System.out.println("Hello");
   } while(potentialsales<accelerationsales);
}
```

Run this sample code,you will understand the problem.